# Problema con FontAwesome 6 y React: "Couldnt find icon"

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

tengo una duda con respecto a FontAwesome y React, me explico:

Estos son los modulos que he instalado para usar `FontAwesome`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  },
```

He creado un archivo donde separe y agregue los iconos que voy a necesitar para mi landing, la he llamado `font-awesome.js` y tengo este codigo:

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {
  faLaravel,
  faWordpressSimple,
  faPhp,
  faJs,
  faBootstrap,
  faGithub,
  faFirefoxBrowser,
  faInstagram,
  faLinkedinIn,
  faTwitter,
  faHtml5,
  faCss3,
  faNodeJs,
  faReact,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";


library.add(
  faLaravel,
  faWordpressSimple,
  faPhp,
  faReact,
  faBootstrap,
  faJs,
  faGithub,
  faFirefoxBrowser,
  faInstagram,
  faInstagram,
  faLinkedinIn,
  faTwitter,
  faHtml5,
  faCss3,
  faNodeJs,
  faPlus
);
```

Y en el lugar donde la ocupo lo mando a llamar, en este caso `my-component.js`:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const PxSkillCard = () => {
  const [skillCardData, setSkillCardData] = useState(null);
  const icons = ["laravel", "wordpress-simple", "php", "reactjs", "node-js", "js"];

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSkillCardData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(LOCAL_URL);
        const data = await response.json();

        setSkillCardData(data.english.skills);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Tuviste un error a la hora de obtener la info: ${error}`);
      }
    }

    getSkillCardData();
  }, []);

  if (!skillCardData) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="items">
        {skillCardData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="item" key={item.id} >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icons[index]} size="xl" />
              <h3 className="">{item.name}.</h3>
              <p style={{ display: "none" }}>{item.description}.</p>
            </div>
          );
        })
        }
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma alternativa y en mi opinión, mas sencilla de utilizar los iconos de FontAwesome es mediante el uso de React-Icons, es mas sencillo de implementar, lo que ahorra tiempo, además que tienes una gran variedad de iconos, no solo de FontAwesome. Para esto puedes instalarlo con:

```
npm install react-icons --save
```

El uso es bastante sencillo, haces el import del icono:

```
import { IconName } from "react-icons/fa";
```

Para usarlo en el componente o pagina que quieres unicamente tienes que ponerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<IconName />
```

Te comparto un ejemplo utilizándolos en App.js

```
import { 
  FaLaravel,
  FaPlus, 
  FaWordpressSimple,
  FaPhp,
  FaJs,
  FaBootstrap,
  FaGithub,
  FaFirefoxBrowser,
  FaInstagram,
  FaLinkedinIn,
  FaTwitter,
  FaHtml5,
  FaCss3,
  FaNodeJs,
  FaReact,
} from "react-icons/fa";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h2>Example of React Icons</h2>
      <div>
        <FaLaravel />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

El icono se comporta como un texto, por lo que si quisieras modificar el css, puedes envolver el icono en una etiqueta `p` y agregarle el `className`:

```
<p className="icon">
  <FaLaravel />
</p>
```

O si utilizas Tailwindcss puedes hacerlo directamente en el icono: `<IconName className='text-red' />`

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono.